# Working with JSON Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a set of JSON object in a text file called text.json which looks like the following:

```
{
  "school": [
    {
      "student": {
        "name": "John",
        "lastname": "Ghram",
        "studentId": "000111"
      }
    },
    {
       "student": {
        "name": "Harry",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "studentId": "000112"
     }
    },
    {
       "teacher": {
       "name": "Teacher One",
       "teacherId": 1001
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The following code is use to read from file

```
var obj = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': true,
            'url': "text.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'success': function (data) {
                obj = data;
            }
        });
        return obj;
    })();
```

When the `obj` is returned to get the name of student name I am using
`obj.school[0].student['name']`. 
is there a way to store all student information as one JSON object called `students` and the teacher to other called `teachers`, so I can access the  info without using the index number. For Eg: `student.name`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You have multiple students. Somehow you have to indicate which one to access. They way you claim to access the data doesn't match the data. Also, learn how asynchronous calls work.

Comment: @Mritunjay: No, that has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Just curious - this would be fairly easy if you are using lodash or underscore. Are you?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. You need to show us real data if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is exactly what arrays are for. You cannot store multiple instances of the `name` property on one object, that makes no sense. How would `student.name` possibly resolve to a single name, if `student` represented multiple students?

Comment: What would be the way to access a student data?

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol I cannot tell, because you have not included valid JSON in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to new an array to store them, you can write a function like this

```
function getStudents(obj)
{
    var res = new Array() ;
    var school = obj['school'] ;
    for(item in school)
    {
        for(q in school[item])
        {
            if(q=="student")//you can change it to "teacher"
            {
                res.push(school[item]) ;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(res) ;
    return res ;//return an array(object) of students;
}
getStudents(obj) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've formatted your json and then applied a for loop to find object keys that match 'student' and then augmented the students object with the name.

If two names are the same, they'll be overwritten, so this isn't the best approach:

```
var obj = {
    "school": [ 
      {"student": { "name":"John",  "lastname": "Ghram", "studentId": 000111 }},  
      {"student": { "name": "Harry","lastname": "Smith", "studentId": 000112 }},
      {"teacher": { "name": "Teacher One", "teacherId": 1001 }}
    ]
};

var i, arr = obj.school, len = arr.length;
var students = Object.create(null);

for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(Object.keys(arr[i])[0] === 'student') students[arr[i].student.name] = arr[i];
}
```

Can now use square-bracket notation:

```
students['John'], students['Harry'], etc
```